# Why does my web application compile but throw Type 'BitmapImage' is not defined. errors while debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My web application project builds and runs just fine. There are no reference or type not defined errors during builds. When I try to load a web form that uses PresentationCore.dll to use BitmapImage, however, I get `Type 'BitmapImage' is not defined.`

Things I have done:

- Included `Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging` at the top of my codebehind file
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project and solution
- Removed and re-added the reference to PresentationCore.dll
- Confirmed that intellisense works on the name `BitmapImage` in my code to identify it as a member of `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`
- Confirmed that there are no instances of the text `Type 'BitmapImage' is not defined.` published on the web already
- Deleted the bin and obj folders completely
- Added PresentationCore as an Imported namespace (so Imports or using statements are not required)
- Also added a reference to WindowsBase
- Used the name `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` instead of just `BitmapImage`
- Re-installed Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Moved all my code to a new Web Application project running framework 4.5.2

Here are the exceptions that are thrown at run-time:

- System.Web.HttpParseException error BC30002: Type 'BitmapImage' is not defined.
- System.Web.HttpCompileException error BC30002: Type 'BitmapImage' is not defined.

Shouldn't these exceptions prevent me from compiling? Why doesn't my reference to PresentationCore.dll work at run-time while debugging if the project builds and runs?

**Update: I have been asked to share some code.**

TestBitmapImage.aspx contents:

`<%@ Page Language="vb" Src="TestBitmapImage.aspx.vb" Inherits="PortalVB.TestBitmapImage" %>`

TestBitmapImage.aspx.vb contents:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Public Class TestBitmapImage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim b As New BitmapImage()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @MickyD thanks & done

Comment: Did you cross check, which .net/asp.net version you are using and which version of `PresentationCore.dll` reference are you trying to add? Make sure your Asp.net's target .net framework is not lower than that of 'PresentationCore.dll'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something strange about including the project namespace in this line along with the use of `Src` and `CodeBehind`:

`<%@ Page Language="vb" Src="TestBitmapImage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestBitmapImage" %>`

`<%@ Page Language="vb" CodeBehind="TestBitmapImage.aspx.vb" Inherits="PortalVB.TestBitmapImage" %>`

I do not understand it, but when I use web forms to create the targets of AJAX calls, I must change the default (second line) to mimic the first.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more things to try are

- Clear the asp.net temporary files folder.
- Look for conflicting assemblies in the GAC